# iPhone Android Recurring Payments API

Tags: android, iphone, payment-processing

I have a web application that supports subscriptions (recurring payments).

I've built an API for mobile apps, the missing part yet, is the billing process, I've got on my backend subscription entity, and transactions (successful and failed).

If anyone has experience in that area. What can you get out of google play / itunes API's regarding the payment processing? In terms of entities/objects and their properties so that the phone app can send to my backend.

Question 2: Does those apis support functionalities such as subscription cancellation, termination, and refund policy?

Comment: You can have subscriptions on iOS; however, you must use Apple's in app purchase API  to complete the transaction and bill the user. After, once the user has paid for their subscription through Apple's API, you are then expected to unlock the products from your server. At the moment, are you trying to do the whole transaction on your server?

Comment: I want to record the transaction and the subscription status on the backend, so I can unlock the product usage for instance and support billing history functionality...and alot of other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

A company called MagicPay offers a program that is called DualPay, this program allows you to process payments on a virtual terminal as well as on iPhone or Android devices.
The benefit of this program is that everything integrates to the virtual terminal and you'll be able to setup recurring billing for your clients.

The downside of this program is that you won't really be able to control the recurring billing from the mobile device, just from the virtual terminal which is pretty much accessible from any computer.

Here is the page where you'll be able to find more information about the program:
http://www.magicpay.net/mobile-payments-with-virtual-payment-gateway/

Hope I helped,
Good Luck!